# Can't change production.ini file

Tags: docker, ckan

I am following the current tutorial for setting up CKAN. (https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-docker-compose.html)

I am not getting the DataStore tab when managing a dataset, so I was trying to follow the section where it says "Datastore and Datapusher". I got everything fine but when it says to edit the "production.ini" file, I am not getting the actual file. It says to run the following command:

`sudo vim $VOL_CKAN_CONFIG/production.ini`

But that just opens an empty file. And yes, I did configure the `$VOL_CKAN_CONFIG` variable like it says before in the tutorial. I am new to Docker and CKAN so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What do `echo $VOL_CKAN_CONFIG` and `ls $VOL_CKAN_CONFIG/*` give?

Comment: echo: `/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker_ckan_config/_data`



ls: `zsh: no matches found: /var/lib/docker/volumes/docker_ckan_config/_data/*`

Comment: That show's that it's not a problem with vim, something hasn't worked in your setup as there is nothing in the config directory.
I'm not familiar with ckan but looking at the docs it suggests something has gone wrong in your setup.

Did you check the logs after the setup, as per the docs? What is the output of 
`docker-compose restart ckan`
`docker ps | grep ckan`
`docker-compose logs -f ckan`

Answer (score 0):

Provided there are only ckan related images/containers, get rid of all volumes/ docker images by running:
`docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq) && docker system prune -af --volumes`
and rebuild:
`docker-compose up -d --build`